# Upgrade from SonarQube 4.3.2 to 4.5LTS (No Response)

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to update SonarQube from 4.3.2 to 4.5LTS.

The last two lines for log are as below:

2015.06.09 16:19:24 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up

2015.06.09 16:19:46 INFO  http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000-exec-1 web[sql]  0ms Executed SQL: SELECT version FROM schema_migrations

And the web page shows "SonarQube is under maintenance. Please check back later."

And then there is no response for over 6 hours without any error message.
Is there anything I can do for this?

(Should I upgrade to 4.4 first and then go 4.5?)

thanks!

Comment: Can you check that you didn't unzip version 4.5 over existing 4.3.2 directory ? Note that direct upgrade from 4.3 to 4.5.x is supported. No need to upgrade to 4.4 as an intermediary step.

Comment: Another explanation : you should check that only a single server access to the db schema. Server 4.3 should be stopped when starting the second instance 4.5.

Comment: 1. 4.5 is a new folder which is unzipped directly from the download page. I copied files under "extentensions"(for jdbc) and "plugins" from 4.3.2 to 4.5.

2. The old server is not running while the upgrade process is working.

Comment: Ok, so please share the full server logs to help investigation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the [http://<< yourserver >>:9000/setup](http://localhost:9000/setup) page and start the migration process. After that the Sonar Instance will return to working state.

Comment: this step is not explained in the upgrade page http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading. this advice works for me.